# unable to create file in the home dir

Tags: php, ubuntu, fopen, file-handling

I am facing an issue that is i want to create a file in my dropbox folder with php script .**my os is Ubuntu 12.04** . dropbox folder path is `/home/ris/dropbox/somefile.txt` .I know i don't have permission to do this .I used this php function to create file

```
<?
$dbdir="/home/ris/Dropbox/";
    if(is_dir($dbdir))
    {

        $myfile = fopen($dbdir."testfile.txt", "w");
         $myfile ? $var="creates" :$var=error_get_last();
        print_r($var);
    }else 
    {
        echo "no dir";  
    }
?>
```

showing me the error

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => fopen(/home/ris/Dropbox/): failed to open stream: Permission denied [file] => /var/www/cronjobs/cron-dbbkup.php [line] => 6 )
```

i just want to upload my backup files in dropbox folder. how it is possible .
Thanks

Comment: Try to give proper access rules to Dropbox `766` `sudo chmod 766 -R /home/ris/Dropbox`

Comment: I was thinking to do this . But I afraid if something wrong happened after change the permission of home dir.

Comment: you can give them back after if something is not going one as planed

Answer (score 0):

According to me if you directly create the file without any path it will automatically be created in the current directory.

Comment: my php file is in var/www folder i want to create file in home/ris/test.txt how it is possible??